# Insertar Post e imagenes en un solo registro

Tags: laravel

Tengo una tabla de post que tiene un campo imagen, y tengo un problema, cuando intento insertar el campo, tengo que comprobar previamente que el usuario ha posteado una imagen, y si es así insertarla. Esto me funcionaba perfectamente cuando la imagen estaba en una tabla independiente, pero si la quiero insertar junto al post inicial, me insertar primero el post y luego la imagen, con lo que se inserta son 2 registros en vez de uno.
Me gustaría usar `eloquent` para esto.

He hecho una prueba de hacer una función dentro de otra función para determinar si el campo imagen existe e insertar una cosa u otra pero no me reconoce el request así que esta solución creo que no es viable.

Os paso el código.

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
     /*******************************************************VALIDACIONES CAMPOS*********************************/
       $validador =  \Validator::make($request->all(),
                    array('titulo' => 'required',
                        'contenido' => 'required',
                     //   'imagen' => 'required|image'
                            ),
                    array(
                        'required' => 'El campo :attribute es requerido ahora mismo', 
                        )
            );
       if ( $validador->fails()) :
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validador);
        endif;   /*******************************************************FIN VALIDACIONES CAMPOS*********************************/ 

                               /*******************************************************CREACION POST*********************************/
        $nombreimagen = 'mesteban_'.time().'.'.$request->file('imagen')->getClientOriginalExtension();

      function devuelveImagen()
      {
            if( $request->HasFile('imagen')):
                  return $nombreimagen;
              else:
                  return 'ruta de imagen personalizada_'.rand(10000,20000);
              endif;
      }

     devuelveImagen();

       $datosaInsertar = 
       array(
            'titulo' => $request->titulo,
            'imagen' => $this->devuelveImagen(),
            'contenido' => $request->contenido,
            'url' => str_slug($request->titulo),
            );
       $creandoPost = \App\modelos\post::create($datosaInsertar);
         \Session::flash('estado','El post de nombre ..:: '.$request->titulo.' ::.. ha sido creado correctamente');

         /*******************************************************FIN CREACION POST*********************************/

         /*******************************************************CREACION IMAGEN*********************************/


         $ruta = public_path('ima\posts\\');


       if($nombreimagen):
           $request->file('imagen')->move($ruta,$nombreimagen);

       //USANDO LIBRERIA INTERVENTION PARA REDIMENSIONAR IMAGEN;
       \Image::make($ruta.$nombreimagen)->resize(300,300)->save();


          //  \App\modelos\post::create(array('imagen'=> $nombreimagen));
        endif;
         /*******************************************************FIN CREACION IMAGEN*********************************/

        return redirect()->to('/admin/posts');
    }
```

MODELO POST

```
<?php

namespace App\modelos;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class post extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'posts';

    protected $fillable = ['titulo','contenido','imagen','url'];

}
```

Comment: Buenas, si te valió la respuesta, por favor, marca la respuesta como valida. Si no es así, edita la pregunta con los posibles fallos/dudas para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tu problema es que no estar guardado el "Modelo"

Te pongo un ejemplo de como lo tengo yo hecho, y me dices si te vale:

```
$validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), (new DirectoriosRequest)->rules($request));

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        \Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator->messages())->withInput();
    }

    $directorio = new Directorio();

    $directorio->categoria = $request->categoria;
    $directorio->subcategoria = $request->subcategoria;
    $directorio->nombre = $request->nombre;
    $directorio->descripcion = $request->descripcion;

    $destinationPath =  env('DIRECTORIO_UPLOAD_DIR', 'admin/directorios');
    $extension = $request->archivo->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $fileName = pathinfo($request->archivo->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME)."_archivo_".rand(11111,99999).'.'.$extension;
    $request->archivo->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
    $directorio->archivo = $fileName;

    if (isset($request->thumbnail)) {
        $destinationPath =  env('DIRECTORIO_UPLOAD_DIR', 'admin/directorios');
        $extension = $request->thumbnail->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileName = pathinfo($request->thumbnail->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME)."_thumbnail_".rand(11111,99999).'.'.$extension;
        $request->thumbnail->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
        $directorio->thumbnail = $fileName;
    }

    $directorio->save();

    return \Redirect::to(action('Admin\DirectorioController@index'));
```

En mi caso el `validator`:

```
Public function rules()
    {
        $rules = [
            'categoria'     => 'required|string',
            'nombre'        => 'required|string',
            'descripcion'   => 'required|string',
            'archivo'       => 'required',
        ];

        return $rules;
    }
}
```

Con eso compruebo que seguro que tiene que existir, sin decirle que tiene que ser una imagen, eso lo hago directamente con HTML5 en el input.

En tu caso no veo el `save()` del `Model`

***Edit:*** Te está creando dos registros porque el segundo `create` no tiene un ID asociado, por tanto para Eloquent en un "Modelo" nuevo. Dale a ese `create` el mismo ID y entonces no creará un nuevo registro.

Comment: Bueno, esa solucion la conocia, pero por eso te comente que preferia hacerlo por eloquent, Respecto a lo de guardar el modelo, esta aqui
$creandoPost = \App\modelos\post::create($datosaInsertar); y si te fijas un poco mas abajo, comentado esta 
//  \App\modelos\post::create(array('imagen'=> $nombreimagen));
pero lo he comentado por que esto es lo que hace la segunda inserccion, de ahi la funcion devuelveImagen() que cree para intentar pasarle el parametro correcto a la imagen en caso de que existe o no, pero esta opcion me da un fallo de request, no se por que

Comment: @KurodoAkabane No entiendo entonces tu "necesidad" de usar "Eloquent". Ya lo estas usando al usar modelos, siempre que uses cualquier cosa estas usando "Eloquent". ¿Que es para tí usar "Eloquent"?. Edit: Te esta haciendo una segunda inserción porque el create no tiene un ID sobre el que hacer la modificación, si le das un ID o recuperas un modelo con ID, no creará uno nuevo.

Comment: ¿Te valió la respuesta?